# "It is" or "it are"

Tags: pronouns, verb-agreement

Does *it* always agree with a singular verb?

For example, does one say (i) or rather (ii)?

- (i) It is the birds he is chasing away.
- (ii) It are the birds he is chasing away.

Comment: ‘The birds’ are not the actual subject anywhere. In the main clause, they are the subject predicative; in the subordinate clause, they are (anaphorically) the object.

Comment: Bram, don't worry, I see a downvote, not mine; so I infer the question is not a good fit even for English learners.

Comment: I thought it was a reasonable question.  Like many questions, the simple answer is readily available pretty much anywhere (*it is*, not **it are*), but there are some nuances that are less obvious which may be harder to look up.  And this question gives us an opportunity to talk about those nuances, which in my opinion adds value to the site.  For this reason, I voted up rather than down.

Comment: @snailboat On other stackexchange sites, posts often get downvoted for being too easy, off-topic, not complete or for bad formatting. I have to guess why it gets downvoted here. I hate it when people don't comment and explain why. Yes, it might be a basic question, but that's why it's English **learners**, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A verb and its subject generally agree in number:

> *It* **is** the birds he is chasing away.
>   *The Great Lakes* **are** the largest surface freshwater system on the Earth. <sup>*(example from [epa.gov](http://www.epa.gov/greatlakes/basicinfo.html))*</sup>

In some dialects and in limited situations, agreement can be [notional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Formal_and_notional_agreement) instead.  In that case, the way you're thinking about it (as either singular or plural) is more important than its grammatical form:

> <sup>%</sup>*The Clash* **are** a well-known band. <sup>*(example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Formal_and_notional_agreement))*</sup>

But agreement with *it* is never notional.  *It* is always singular, so the following sentence is unacceptable:

> **It* **are** a well-known band.

Some subjects are **conjoined** (consisting of at least two conjuncts, **A and B**), in which case the verb typically<sup><sup>†</sup></sup> takes plural agreement, even if the individual conjuncts are singular:

> *He and I* **are** a couple.
>   Both *he and it* **are** far too valuable to be anywhere but a secure installation.  <sup>*(example from [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/))*</sup>

As you can see, *it* is sometimes followed by *are* in these cases because agreement is with the entire subject *he and it*, not just with *it*, and this subject is plural.

Other subjects are **disjoined** (consisting of at least two disjuncts, **A or B**), and in this case the verb generally agrees with each disjunct individually:

‹ꜱɪɴɢᴜʟᴀʀ› or ‹ꜱɪɴɢᴜʟᴀʀ› **is**

or

‹ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ› or ‹ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ› **are**

But sometimes singular and plural noun phrases are coordinated, and we end up with a **number conflict**.  This conflict has to be resolved somehow, and [different speakers have different preferences for doing so](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1293).  For example, some prefer agreement with **the plural disjunct**, while others prefer agreement with **the closer disjunct**:

‹ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ› or ‹ꜱɪɴɢᴜʟᴀʀ› **is**  　　←　agreement with **the closer disjunct**
　　‹ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ› or ‹ꜱɪɴɢᴜʟᴀʀ› **are**　　←　agreement with **the plural disjunct**

But if we put the plural disjunct second, then the plural disjunct *is* the closer disjunct:

‹ꜱɪɴɢᴜʟᴀʀ› or ‹ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ› **are**　　←　agreement with **the closer disjunct**
　　‹ꜱɪɴɢᴜʟᴀʀ› or ‹ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ› **are**　　←　agreement with **the plural disjunct**

So in these cases we can make both groups happy by putting the plural disjunct second.  Many style guides recommend doing exactly this.  However, some speakers would prefer to avoid this conflict altogether; these speakers would prefer rewriting the sentence so that they don't have to pick one or the other.

---

*In this answer, I've used the following symbols:*
　　<sup>%</sup> *marks a sentence that is considered standard English by some speakers but not others*
　　* *marks a sentence that is considered nonstandard by all speakers*

*<sup>†</sup> The matter of agreement with conjoined subjects is actually more complicated than this.  See e.g. Heidi Lorimor's thesis, [*Conjunctions and Grammatical Agreement*](http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/hml003/lorimor%20thesis.pdf).*

Answer (score 2):

One would say

(i) It is the birds he is chasing away.

It is never acceptable to say "It are [...]" in the English language.

Answer (score 1):

"it" is always singular. In the case of your example sentence, "the birds" can be considered as referring to the group, not the individuals.

Comment: Sparr, and what does 'It is the birds he is chasing away' mean!? Shouldn't it be '**They are** the birds he is chasing away'?

Comment: @Whiskey- What's little Billy doing out there by the bird feeder with his BB gun?  He's trying to chase away the cats so that the birds can come eat.  Hmm, it is the birds he's chasing away...

Comment: @Jim, interesting! Is this vernacular or normal speech? Or, is the chasing the object of that 'it is'?

Comment: @Whiskey- It's normal speech.  *The birds* is being treated as a singular entity, i.e., ***a*** flock, or ***a*** covey, etc.

Comment: And if the birds could speak, they'd say *"We are the birds he is chasing away,  d a r n     i t !"* :)