# Using 'either she or I' in interrogative sentence, which is correct? "Is either she or I ," or "am either she or I"

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement

Using 'either she or I' in interrogative sentence, which is correct? "Is either she or I ," or "am either she or I"

The sentence I am thinking of is **"Is either she or I speaking on the stage?"**

In normal sentence we use plural verb like "either she or I am." But in questioning sentence, I don't know which is correct.

Comment: Can you add the full sentence please?

Comment: Is either she or I speaking on the stage?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Do you mean will not be misunderstood? Do you mean is the only version people ever use? You're going to have to define correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kim or I was/were rejected](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37246/kim-or-i-was-were-rejected)